# PyQt Targeting of Specific Objects

Tags: css, user-interface, pyqt

This is my first time posting in stackoverflow so please bear with me. I am trying to create a GUI using PyQt for a research application and am having some stylesheet trouble. This program uses CSS for stylesheets. I want to know how to target a specific QCheckBox.

i.e)   If I type:

```
#PlotArea QCheckBox
{
background: #FFFFFF      /*changes background of checkbox button to white*/
}
```

Then both of the two checkboxes now have a white background.

I have named the check boxes differently, as checkBox_phase and checkBox_showDataLogging.

Can I use their names to target specific boxes? Or do I have to create different frames for each of them and call them by their frames?

Please ask me questions!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just as a wild guess, one of othese may work: `#PlotArea QCheckBox[name="checkBox_phase"]` or `#checkBox_phase`

Comment: The second one worked perfectly! Thanks a ton!\